# Hide the actual location of a node on Views with GMap Module

Tags: views, google-maps

What I'm trying to achieve is to hide the actual location of a node, either by replacing the marker with a circle, overlaying or inserting a radius(`circle`) around the actual location. Tried to do this with the help of macro builder but it doesn't accept replacement patterns in order to send the coordinates to the `circle` macro.

Any help is welcome, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by adding a marker in a circle format, setting `maxzoom` and clearing all cache.